# Twilio multiple agents one number for outgoing calls

Tags: twilio, voice

I would like to setup easy **Click To Call for outgoing call**s using Twilio REST API. Let's say is CRM-like system with php.

Consider Example:

1. Agent1 can enter his own personal number in his *Profile/User Settings*
2. Agent1 as a logged in user clicks on customer phone number
3. Call is initiated **From** twilio verified number **To** Agent1 personal phone number
4. When Agent1 picks up the phone, twilio will connect the customer to the call using Dial twiml verb
5. Agent1 can terminate phone call anytime from Web interface
6. Agent2 can do the same with another customer as in the step 1.

I am little bit confused about twilio numbers.

- Can one twilio number handle multiple outgoing simultaneous calls?
- I don't know if i should put twilio number config in the *Global Settings* for whole website
- or rather put it to the *User Settings* so for example 10 users/agents can have 10 different twilio numbers

Please can you advice me about good and bad practice or point me right to the docs section, i am planning to do incoming calls aswell in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> Can one twilio number handle multiple outgoing simultaneous calls?

One Twilio number can handle multiple incoming/outgoing calls at the same time.

> I don't know if i should put twilio number config in the Global Settings for whole website or rather put it to the User Settings so for example 10 users/agents can have 10 different twilio numbers

This depends on how you want the calls to appear. If you want each agent to have  a different number then you should set this at user level, if you want one number to work for all agents, then you can probably set this at application level.

For future thinking, if you plan to take incoming calls and direct them to particular agents then you might need one number per agent. If your incoming calls will just be directed to an agent that is free, then one number will suffice.

Just as an extra note, if you have a web interface then rather than calling to the agent's personal phone, you could implement [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client) and make calls directly from the web browser.